# Java: Character comparison

Tags: java, character

I am pretty new to java and just got stuck on a seemingly silly problem.
`'H'>'e'` gives `false` and  `'h'>'e'` gives `true`. What is going on here?

Comment: Check out an ASCII table and it all makes sense. However, because of the unintuitive nature of such code, I'd advice to avoid such things - like comparing characters. Better to be more explicit, for example by casting the chars to int. This way, it becomes more obvious what's going on.

Comment: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html

Comment: I forgot to mention another thing. How do I do a lexicographical comparison?

Comment: If you want to have a more natural comparison, use a Collator. But what you have **is** a lexicographical comparison.

Comment: A Java `char` is a UTF-16 code unit, not ASCII as some say. UTF-16 is one of several encodings for the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. This is just like .NET, JavaScript, VB6,…. And HTML and XML documents are sequences of Unicode codepoints, regardless of the document encoding. As for lexicographic orderings: [ <  <  < ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/mathematical_alphanumeric_symbols/utf8test.htm), maybe you do have some use for that; They are completely ordered and invariant, rather than partial and culture-specific.

Answer (score 5):

When comparing `char`s, the ASCII-code of the `char`s are compared.

Here we have:

- H = 72
- h = 104
- e = 101

So basically you are comparing

```
'H'>'e' // =  72 > 101 = false
'h'>'e' // = 104 > 101 = true
```

Comment: [ASCII: printable characters on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters)

Answer (score 1):

The comparison is on the basis of ASCII Values.

```
The ASCII value for 'H' is 72
For 'h' is 104    
and for 'e' is 101
```

Hence 'H'>'e' gives false and 'h'>'e' gives true