# Count Vowels and Consonants

Tags: java, if-statement

I was exploring this code which gives a count of vowels and consonants, but didn't understand this `else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')` line of code. Please tell me what's the logic behind it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Vowels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter string");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        int vowl = 0;
        int conso = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char ch = str.charAt(i);
            if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u') {
                vowl++;
            } else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
                conso++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(vowl);
        System.out.println(conso);
    }
}
```

Comment: It checks that `ch` is a letter in the range abc...z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

- notice the if statement catches all vowels
- whats ever is not a vowel will either be a capital letter, a number, a special character or consonants

  else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
  this checks if its not a vowel does it atleast fall in the range of small letter 'a'-'z' and is not a special charecter or a number.( we knonw its not a vowel but is it in the ascii range 26=a -51=z)

refer to the ASCII table to understand the range comparison

Comment: Note that Java works with Unicode internally - without knowing the author's preferred language the ASCII chart is not appropriate. And why should upper case vowels be counted as consonants?

Answer (score 2):

A benefit of chars is that you can operate with them like if they were integers.

For example, you can do you this as well `'a' + 3 = 'd'`

Meaning that `'a' < 'd' = true`.

Comment: In that case you treat chars like bytes, which is only true if you operate in ASCII. Even UTF-8 can have national special characters that are completely ignored by this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The comparison of characters the way it is done can create confusion, as you can see from [Java: Character comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43450659/java-character-comparison).

Basically @TDG is correct by saying that ch is checked to be between 'a' and 'z', and thus the check might be translated as "is ch a lower case character?"

The tricky part is that depending on the language people use the expectation can be different, especially since language specific characters are not taken into account. In German language, 'ö' would definitely qualify as lower case character but is not in the range of the check. The complexity may get evident by studying the [Unicode code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/).

The best check is to use [Character.isLowerCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase(char)).

Answer (score 1):

`char` is a character that represented by a number which is the index of the character in the `ASCII/unicode` table, since the the alphabet characters are arranged in order in the `ASCII` table, the following code checks if the `ch` is in the range of the lowercase alphabet characters representation which is `97` to `122` in the table.

using `(int) ch` you can see the decimal value of the character and can compare it with the index in the ASCII table.

you can see the ASCII table here:https://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.bharat;

public class CaptchaGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        String s = "hello world welcome the programming world";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        StringBuffer sb1 = new StringBuffer();
        String k = null;
        int vc = 0;
        char ch[] = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
        int v = s.length();
        System.out.println("the length of the given string is which includes with spaces:"+v);
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                v--;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("the length of the given string after removing the spaces:"+v);
        

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            if (s.charAt(i) != ' ') {

                for (int j = 0; j < ch.length; j++) {

                    if (s.charAt(i) == ch[j]) {
                        //System.out.println("vowels");
                        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
                        vc++;
                        k = sb.toString();

                    }

                }

            }

        }
        System.out.println("vowels count is:" + vc);
        int l = k.length();
        int m = v - l;
        System.out.println("the consonants in the string:"+m);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.